# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

Tags: c#, console, numbers, calculator, console.readline

I am creating an C# calculator console using ***visual studio and code*** and when I am typing and debugging my application I got this error *"Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'"*.  I think my code was not compatible. Can somebody help me?

```
Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tCalculator in C#\r");
Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t-----------------\r");
 
Console.WriteLine("\t\tEnter First Number\r"); 
double num1 = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("\t\tSelect an Operator: ( +, -, *, /, ^)\r");

 
double opp = Console.ReadLine(); ---- WITH THIS LINE??**
 
Console.WriteLine("\t\tEnter second Number\r"); 
double num2 =  Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: I tried both but I still got errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular line, you are expecting an operator. This should be represented by a `char` or `string`, rather than double.

```
Console.WriteLine("\t\tSelect an Operator: ( +, -, *, /, ^)\r");
string opp = Console.ReadLine(); // Change here
```

The operators `+-*/^` are not number and cannot be represented by double.You can add additional checks to ensure, the User has entered a valid operator

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Console.ReadLine()` is returning string. But you are trying to put that string in your `double` variable. If you are expecting user to type in the operator (+, -, ...), then make your opp variable of type `string`. If is user supposed to send a number for operator(eg. 1 for '+', 2 for '-', 3 for '*'), then change the line to

```
double opp = Douoble.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

In both cases you should let user know what type of input are you expecting.

If anything is not clear, let me know for sure